# Ionic serve -l showing older errors?

Tags: ionic-framework

i get this bug where sometime old errors appear again in ionic.
A new serve helps but it is pretty annoying because sometimes when fixing erros you still get the error message even the error is already removed.

I use `ionic serve -l` to start my app.

Might be a problem with cashes? Anybody experiencing the same? And is there a solution/or workarround to this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you please check these github issues to see if you're facing the same issue?: [issue1](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-cli/issues/2950), [issue2](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-app-scripts/issues/1369) and [issue3](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-app-scripts/issues/1132)